# Using Azure DevOps REST API how can I get the list of jobs that were executed on the given agent?

Tags: azure-devops

I could not find the respective REST API.

We have on-prem Azure DevOps 2020.

Fiddler does not help, there is no clear request there. The data seems to be embedded within HTML returned from the server.

**EDIT 1**

There is a very inefficient way - fetch all the builds with their timelines and filter those that have run or still running on the given agent. This is very resource greedy way to do it and I would not consider it as an answer.